Why is my css animation not working on closing the element using React useState hook
I have build a sliding submenu with React, Typescript and Tailwind.
The related submenu is showing using React useState hook.
See the working code sandbox here.
Why is my close css animation not working data-[state=closed]:animate-[submenu-hide_300ms]? The open animation data-[state=open]:animate-[submenu-show_300ms] works.
How to fix this?
Update:
Instead of doing:
{clickedItem === item && (
        <ul
          data-state={dataSate}
          className="fixed top-0 flex h-svh w-[300px] flex-col bg-red-300 ease-in data-[state=closed]:animate-[submenu-hide_300ms] data-[state=open]:animate-[submenu-show_300ms]"
        >
          <li>
            <button
              onClick={() => setClickedItem(null)}
              type="button"
              className="flex items-center p-2"
            >
              <span className="mr-10">Back</span>
              <span className="font-bold">{item.title}</span>
            </button>
          </li>
          {item.items?.map((item) => (
            <li key={item.url}>
              {item.items && item.items.length > 0 ? (
                <button
                  onClick={() => handleClick(item)}
                  className="flex w-full justify-between p-2"
                  type="button"
                >
                  {item.title}
                  <span>[+]</span>
                </button>
              ) : (
                <a href={item.url} className="p-2">
                  {item.title}
                </a>
              )}
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
       )}

I tried the following (show/hide it with css instead of React useState), but the animation is still not working when hiding the element?:
            <ul
              data-state={dataSate}
              className={`${clickedItem === item ? 'left-0 animate-[submenu-show_300ms]' : 'left-[-375px] animate-[submenu-hide_300ms] overflow-hidden'} fixed top-0 flex h-svh w-[375px] flex-col bg-red-300 ease-in`}
            >
              <li>
                <button
                  onClick={() => setClickedItem(null)}
                  type="button"
                  className="flex items-center p-2"
                >
                  <span className="mr-10">Back</span>
                  <span className="font-bold">{item.title}</span>
                </button>
              </li>
              {item.items?.map((item) => (
                <li key={item.url}>
                  {item.items && item.items.length > 0 ? (
                    <button
                      onClick={() => handleClick(item)}
                      className="flex w-full justify-between p-2"
                      type="button"
                    >
                      {item.title}
                      <span>[+]</span>
                    </button>
                  ) : (
                    <a href={item.url} className="p-2">
                      {item.title}
                    </a>
                  )}
                </li>
              ))}
            </ul>


clickedItem === item condition is not true as Back button resets the value. Because of that, ReactJS doesn't show the component. And, if component is not exists then no css will trigger.

@RaviNain Thanks, I updated my question. Do you have an idea why it's not working?

You will need to fix the css, hide should transform from 300px to 0.
@keyframes submenu-hide {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(300px);
  }

  to {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

See working example: https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/slide-menu-transition-p4t8mm
